# How to merge two stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have two stored procedures one for INSERT and second for Update and I'd like to merge them in one so could you please tell me which satement should I use for that ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Tools
(@CategoryID_1 int,
 @CategoryName_2 nvarchar(100),
 @Description_3 ntext)

AS INSERT INTO Categories 
 (CategoryID,
 CategoryName,
 Description) 

VALUES 
(@CategoryID_1,
 @CategoryName_2,
 @Description_3)
```

go

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Tools1

     (@CategoryID_1     [int],
 @CategoryID_2  [int],
 @CategoryName_3    [nvarchar](50),
 @Description_4     [ntext],

AS UPDATE [Teachdb].[dbo].[Categories] 

SET  [CategoryID]    = @CategoryID_2,
 [CategoryName]  = @CategoryName_3,
 [Description]   = @Description_4,

WHERE 
( [CategoryID]   = @CategoryID_1)
go
```

GO

Comment: The 2nd procedure seems incomplete

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can merge two store procedure code in below way by passing @Mode value..

```
/*
For Insert 
exec Tools @Mode='Insert', @CategoryID='1', @CategoryName='DemoCat', @Description='demoDesc'

For Update
exec Tools @Mode='UPDATE', @CategoryID='1', @CategoryName='DemoCatupdate', @Description='demoDescupdate'

*/

CREATE PROCEDURE Tools
(
    @Mode nvarchar(100), -- Use for insert or Update
    @CategoryID int,
    @CategoryName nvarchar(100),
    @Description ntext
)

AS 
BEGIN 
    IF @Mode = 'INSERT'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName, Description) 
        VALUES (@CategoryID, @CategoryName, @Description)
    END
    ELSE IF @Mode = 'UPDATE'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Categories] 
            SET  [CategoryID]    = @CategoryID,
                [CategoryName]  = @CategoryName,
                [Description]   = @Description
        WHERE ([CategoryID]   = @CategoryID)
    END
END
go
```

Comment: Receiving following:                                           Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Tools, Line 4
Line 4: Incorrect syntax near '@CategoryID'.
Server: Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Tools, Line 11
Must declare the variable '@Mode'.
Server: Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Tools, Line 14
Must declare the variable '@CategoryID'.
Server: Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Tools, Line 16
Must declare the variable '@Mode'.
Server: Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Tools, Line 19
Must declare the variable '@CategoryID'.

Comment: Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Tools, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: please up the question if you like

Comment: I'd be glad Man but it says that to vote up I need 15 reputation for that !

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to change the structure of the stored procedure (by adding an additional parameter), you can use the MERGE statement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx

One note, though - while I love the MERGE statement, there seems to be an [increasing number of bugs](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug) being found with it.  I suggest to not use it unless you understand what you are doing (no cargo cult programming), and have reviewed the issues to see if your scenario is included.